# How to find all possible trains from Source and Destination?

Tags: mysql

I have a table named Route that stores all possible Routes of Trains.

[image]

I need to write a query to find all possible Train_ID such that Station_ID of Source = "NDLS" and Station_ID of Destination = "KNP".

My attempt:

> `Select t.Train_ID from Route as t,Route as d where t.Train_ID = d.Train_ID and t.Stop_Number < d.Stop_Number and t.Station_ID = "KNP" and d.Station_ID = "NDLS"`;

But this is returning empty set.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.train_id
        , case when t.station_id = 'NDLS' then t.station_id end as source
        , case when t.station_id = 'KNP' then t.station_id end as destination
   from route t;
```

This will give you train_id in first column, second column would be train_id with source as 'NDLS' and third column would be as destination as 'KNP'.

You might get null for destination where source value is presnt and vice versa.

I hope this is ok for you.

Comment: The order in which stop_numbers occur appears to be relevant